# Bounds for the sequence $\frac{n!}{n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum \frac{n!}{n^n}$$ 
I was trying to show if the above converges or not and I couldn't and a solution shows that

[image: entero]

and since we know $\sum\frac{2}{n^2}$ converges then $\sum\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges by comparison test. But I don't understand how they got the bounds to be $\frac{2}{n^2}$

Comment: Look at the first two factors. And then look what you can say about the other factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint 1**
$$\frac{2}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{2}{n}$$
**Hint 2**
$$\forall k\in\{1,2,...,n\} \frac{k}{n} \leq 1$$

Comment: Couldn't you also have $\frac{1}{n}$ as the bounds

Comment: @reifi - $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent, so this bound is senseless